# Why is $\lim_\limits{n \to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\{X \geq n+1\})\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n}a_j = 0$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable such that $\mathbb{P}(\{X \in \mathbb{N}\}) =1$. Besides, $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in [0, \infty)^{\mathbb{N}}$. We must show that if $$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (a_1 + \ldots + a_j)\mathbb{P}(\{X=j\}) < \infty
$$
that then $$
\lim_{n \to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\{X \geq n+1\})\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j = 0.
$$
In an earlier thread I asked why 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} (a_1 + \ldots + a_j)\mathbb{P}(\{X=j\}) + \mathbb{P}(\{X \geq n + 1\})\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j = \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_j \mathbb{P}(\{X \geq j\})$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Because of this amazing community, we came to an answer: (https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2024760/). I've tried the following things:

I know that $$
\mathbb{P}(\{X \geq n +1\}) = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(\{X = k\})
$$
So we could rewrite $$
\lim_{n \to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\{X \geq n+1\})\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j = \lim_{n \to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(\{X = k\})\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j
$$
And from here I didn't really know what to do. So this is where it becomes 'iffy'. So this part is more of a question. Is it that when I say $$
\lim_{n \to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(\{X = k\}) =\sum_{k=\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(\{X = k\})
$$
...? It feels incredibly wrong. But maybe it is something I can work with?

The other route I tried to take, was to say that when $$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (a_1 + \ldots + a_j)\mathbb{P}(\{X=j\}) < \infty
$$
that we must have $$
\lim (a_1 + \ldots + a_j)\mathbb{P}(\{X=j\}) = 0
$$
right? Because if a series converge, $\sum a_n$, then $\lim a_n$ must be equal to 0. But now I'm a bit confused, because should I say $$
\lim_{j \to \infty} (a_1 + \ldots + a_j)\mathbb{P}(\{X=j\}) = 0
$$
or  $$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_1 + \ldots + a_j)\mathbb{P}(\{X=j\}) = 0
$$
The latter doesn't really make sense to me, but this gets confusing so fast for me. From here I would try to argue that $$
\lim (a_1 + \ldots + a_j) = 0
$$
or $$
\lim \mathbb{P}(\{X=j\}) = 0
$$
and from here I would try to conclude that $$
\lim_{n \to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\{X \geq n+1\})\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j = 0.
$$
But it feels like I'm missing a lot of steps, or like I'm taking the wrong steps. Thanks in advance!